# Adding a field with a unique value to vector layer in kml file (need this to burn values with gdal.RasterizeLayer)

Tags: raster, gdal, kml, fields-attributes, rasterization

I would like to create a field `ID` in my `kml` file, with a unique value so that I can use `gdal.RasterizeLayer` to burn the value to an image like this:

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=ID"])
```

This means I need to create an attribute called `ID` in my `.kml` file so that `gdal.RasterizeLayer` will be able to recognize this and burn the correct `ID` value. I tried this and it seems like I create a new field but when I run `gdal.RasterizeLayer`, nothing is rasterized. My current `kml` file has several `Placemark`/`Polygon` objects and I wish to give each of them a unique id.

```
import pykml.parser as kml_parser
from lxml import etree

kml_file = 'test.kml'

with open(kml_file) as f:
    root = kml_file.parse(f).getroot()

for i, Placemark in enumerate(root.Document.Folder.Placemark):
    Placemark.addattr('id', i + 1)

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('new.kml')
```

Does anyone know what the proper way to create attributes in `kml` file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `ID` field simply using the GDAL Python bindings without introducing further dependencies:

**(GDAL >= 2.1.0)**

```
from osgeo import gdal

path = "mask.kml"
ds = gdal.OpenEx(path)
sql = "select FID as ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, ..., FIELDN FROM {}".format(ds.GetLayer().GetName())
ds2 = gdal.VectorTranslate("mask_with_IDs.kml", ds, format = 'KML', SQLStatement = sql, SQLDialect = "OGRSQL")
ds2 = None
```

where `FID` (i.e. feature id) is a special field available in [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html#ogr_sql_special_fields), while `FIELD1, FIELD2, ..., FIELDN` are your fields of interest.

---

**(GDAL < 2.1.0)**

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os

ogr.UseExceptions()

inFileName = "mask.kml"
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("KML")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inFileName, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()
result = inDataSource.ExecuteSQL("select FID, * from {}".format(inLayer.GetName()))

outFileName = "mask_with_IDs.kml"
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("KML")
if os.path.exists(outFileName):
    outDriver.DeleteDataSource(outFileName)
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outFileName)
outLayer = outDataSource.CopyLayer(result, "mask_with_IDs")

inDataSource.ReleaseResultSet(result)
outDataSource = None
```

Comment: Is `FIELDN` supposed to represent each of the polygons? Because I have multiple polygon objects that I'd like to give a unique id value to.

Comment: Also, I am stuck with using gdal version `1.10.1`. So there isn't `gdal.OpenEx` and `gdal.VectorTranslate`, is there a way around this using this version? Thanks!

Comment: `FIELD1 ... FIELDN` (fictitious names) are the N attributes associated to each feature (polygon).
In `GDAL 1.10.1`, you should import the `ogr`module (in place of `gdal`) and use the `ExecuteSQL` datasource method. It's more complex to achieve the result.

Comment: I've added an example also for GDAL < 2.1.0. Hope this helps!